# Regex to pull uppercase words and timestamps?

Tags: regex

I'm quite inexperienced with Regex and even though I would like to figure it out myself, I'm not sure how to get started.

I would like to develop a Ruby scan Regex that takes a string and returns an array of strings.  The Regex should identify stock market ticker symbols, and also include short timestamps (inc. -1d, -1m, -1y) if they follow the ticker.

As an example:

```
How is AMZN-1d today and what about MSFT?
```

would return...

```
["AMZN-1d", "MSFT"]
```

Additionally, if this could be expanded on to the following Regex, which gets the ticker symbols, but not timestamps - that would be brilliant!

```
scan(/[\b\$]?[A-Z]{1,}\.[A-Z]+\b|[\b\$]?[A-Z]{2,}\b|\$[A-Z]{1,}\b|\b[A-Z]{1,}\$/)
```

Comment: What would be the best way identify tickers in your scenario? According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol): `"stock tickers are typically between 1 and 4 letters"` - but that's a bit vague! Can we always assume they are 4 upper case characters, in your case? Or can we work from a complete list of all possible tickers? Or is it okay to grab a  few false positives, and manually delete these? (I see you already have a partial regex solution; I'm wondering whether this could be simplified, improved,or a non-regex solution used instead.)

Comment: Try [`/(?:\$?\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\.[A-Z]+\b)?|\b[A-Z]+\$)(-\d[a-zA-Z]+)?/`](http://rubular.com/r/bGxAvREoFZ)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You probably meant to include the first capture group there: [`/(\$?\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\.[A-Z]+\b)?|\b[A-Z]+\$)(-\d[a-zA-Z]+)?/ `](http://rubular.com/r/bGxAvREoFZ)

Comment: these answers are helpful @TomLord you're follow-up returned [["AMZN", "-1d"], ["MSFT", nil]] for the example I gave, ideally I'd like a 1-dimensional array as in the example.

Comment: @TomLord: I did not mean to use any capturing groups, the last one should actually be non-capturing. [`(?:\$?\b[A-Z]{2,}(?:\.[A-Z]+\b)?|\b[A-Z]+\$)(?:-\d[a-zA-Z]+)?`](http://rubular.com/r/WW2GeSRuEu). However, I'd just use `/\b\p{Lu}{2,}(?:-\d\p{L}+)?/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/\b\p{Lu}{2,}(?:-\d\p{L}+\b)?/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/mqHGUlThrx)

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\p{Lu}{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase letters
- `(?:-\d\p{L}+\b)?` - 1 or zero sequences (due to the `?` quantifier) of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d` - a digit (add a `+` quantifier to match 1 or more digits if more than 1 can occur)
  - `\p{L}+`  - 1 or more letters

If you only need to match ASCII characters, replace `\d` with `[0-9]`, `\p{L}` with `[a-zA-Z]` and `\p{Lu}` with `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation

Comment: An [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/55lF8v): `puts "How is AMZN-1d today and what about MSFT?".scan(/\b\p{Lu}{2,}(?:-\d\p{L}+\b)?/)` displays `AMZN-1d` and `MSFT` results.

Answer (score 0):

You specifications are incomplete. So it is not possible to give a completely valid answer.

You may try using something like this.

```
/([A-Z]{2,}-\d[dmy])|([A-Z]{2,})/g
```

I'm assuming that ticker symbols will have a minimum length of two characters.

Comment: Hey niyasc that's close, I'm getting [["AMZN-1d", nil], [nil, "MSFT"]]  returned, ideally I'd like ["AMZN-1d", "MSFT"].  Let me know how I can improve specifications.  To flesh it out a bit more, I'm looking for uppercase tickers 2 to 4 letters, and if they are followed by (-1d, -1m, -1y), to include that too.